# Can some one explain why React component re-renders if chrome tab is minimized or switched to other tab

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rerender

Im new to react and trying to learn hooks, I have a check that will invalid class if value is failing condition, however after sometime react is adding the class after sometime even though the form has value and that also happens if tabs are switched. The entire login component re renders , value is treated as empty causing react page to crash

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useReducer } from "react";

import Card from "../UI/Card/Card";
import classes from "./Login.module.css";
import Button from "../UI/Button/Button";

const Login = (props) => {
  console.log("Login Component Re-renders");
  // const [enteredEmail, setEnteredEmail] = useState("");
  // const [emailIsValid, setEmailIsValid] = useState();
  // const [enteredPassword, setEnteredPassword] = useState("");
  // const [passwordIsValid, setPasswordIsValid] = useState();
  const [formIsValid, setFormIsValid] = useState();

  const emailReducer = (state, action) => {
    // console.log(action, state);
    if (action.type === "User_Input") {
      return { value: action.val, isValid: action.val.includes("@") };
    }
    if (action.type === "Input_Blur") {
      return { value: state.val, isValid: state.value.includes("@") };
    }
    return { value: "", isValid: false };
  };

  const [emailState, dispatchEmail] = useReducer(emailReducer, {
    value: "",
    isValid: null,
  });

  const passwordReducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === "User_Input") {
      return { value: action.val, isValid: action.val.trim().length > 6 };
    }
    if (action.type === "Input_Blur") {
      return { value: state.val, isValid: state.value?.trim().length > 6 };
    }
    return { value: "", isValid: false };
  };

  const [passwordState, dispatchPassword] = useReducer(passwordReducer, {
    value: "",
    isValid: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {}, []);

  const { isValid: emailIsValid } = emailState;
  const { isValid: passwordIsValid } = passwordState;

  useEffect(() => {
    const identifier = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Checking Form Validity");

      setFormIsValid(emailIsValid && passwordIsValid);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      console.log("Clean Up");
      clearTimeout(identifier);
    };
  }, [emailIsValid, passwordIsValid]);

  const emailChangeHandler = (event) => {
    // console.log(formIsValid);
    dispatchEmail({ type: "User_Input", val: event.target.value });
    setFormIsValid(emailState.isValid && passwordState.isValid);
  };

  const validateEmailHandler = () => {
    dispatchEmail({ type: "Input_Blur" });
  };

  const passwordChangeHandler = (event) => {
    // console.log(formIsValid);
    dispatchPassword({ type: "User_Input", val: event.target.value });
    setFormIsValid(emailState.isValid && passwordState.isValid);
  };

  const validatePasswordHandler = () => {
    dispatchPassword({ type: "Input_Blur" });
  };

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.onLogin(emailState.value, passwordState.value);
  };

  return (
    <Card className={classes.login}>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div
          className={`${classes.control} ${
            emailState.isValid === false ? classes.invalid : ""
          }`}
        >
          <label htmlFor="email">E-Mail</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            value={emailState.value}
            onChange={emailChangeHandler}
            onBlur={validateEmailHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div
          className={`${classes.control} ${
            passwordState.isValid === false ? classes.invalid : ""
          }`}
        >
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            value={passwordState.value}
            onChange={passwordChangeHandler}
            onBlur={validatePasswordHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <Button type="submit" className={classes.btn} disabled={!formIsValid}>
            Login
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: Please share a reproduction through StackBlitz.

Answer (score -1):

You are using useState to manage the form validity state, but this might cause unnecessary re-renders and performance issues.You can use form libraries like `React Hook Form` or `Formik`which provides powerful custom hooks to validate your form with minimal re-renders and a constraint-based validation API.

You can do something like that:

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "../UI/Card/Card";
import classes from "./Login.module.css";
import Button from "../UI/Button/Button";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as yup from "yup";


const schema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email().required(),
  password: yup.string().min(7).required(),
});

const Login = (props) => {
  console.log("Login Component Re-renders");


  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({ resolver: yup.resolver(schema) });

  const submitHandler = (data) => {
    props.onLogin(data.email, data.password);
  };

  return (
    <Card className={classes.login}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitHandler)}>
        <div
          className={`${classes.control} ${
            errors.email ? classes.invalid : ""
          }`}
        >
          <label htmlFor="email">E-Mail</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            {...register("email")} 
          />
        </div>
        <div
          className={`${classes.control} ${
            errors.password ? classes.invalid : ""
          }`}
        >
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            {...register("password")} 
          />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <Button type="submit" className={classes.btn}>
            Login
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. May be there's a hard requirement of using only native hooks, no external libraries?

Comment: You might want to use the useEffect hook to validate your form inputs on change and blur events. You can also use a custom hook to encapsulate the validation logic and reuse it for different inputs.